# merge some line start with special character

Tags: awk, aws

I have some log like this:

```
2023-11-15T08:59:28.000000+00:00 database-1 # Time: 231115  8:59:28
# User@Host: rdsadmin[rdsadmin] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 3  Schema:   QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.000123  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 49
SET timestamp=1700038768;
SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=60 FOR SELECT 1;
```

Can you help me to merge some line start with `#` character to one line like this:

```
2023-11-15T08:59:28.000000+00:00 database-1 # Time: 231115  8:59:28# User@Host: rdsadmin[rdsadmin] @ localhost []# Thread_id: 3  Schema:   QC_hit: No# Query_time: 0.000123  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 49
SET timestamp=1700038768;
SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=60 FOR SELECT 1;
```

I using `awscli` to tail and want to show default log from aws rds.

I have try with this command but not work

```
aws logs tail /aws/rds/instance/database-1/slowquery --log-stream-names database-1 --follow |  sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\#/ #/g'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '
  {
    printf "%s", ((/^#/ || NR==1) ? "" : ORS )$0
  }
  END {
    if (NR) print ""
  }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    /^#/ { rec = rec OFS $0; next }
    NR>1 { print rec }
    { rec = $0 }
    END { print rec }
' file
2023-11-15T08:59:28.000000+00:00 database-1 # Time: 231115  8:59:28 # User@Host: rdsadmin[rdsadmin] @ localhost [] # Thread_id: 3  Schema:   QC_hit: No # Query_time: 0.000123  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0 # Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 49
SET timestamp=1700038768;
SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=60 FOR SELECT 1;
```

With the above we build up line by line and store the multi-line record in `rec` and print it when the next record begins. That way if you have anything you need to do with a record before printing it, you have it in `rec`. If you need to retain the individual lines to do something before printing `rec` then just tweak the above to store a record separator between lines:

```
awk '
    /^#/ { rec = rec RS $0; next }
    NR>1 { prt() }
    { rec = $0 }
    END { prt() }
    function prt() { gsub(RS,OFS,rec); print rec }
' file
2023-11-15T08:59:28.000000+00:00 database-1 # Time: 231115  8:59:28 # User@Host: rdsadmin[rdsadmin] @ localhost [] # Thread_id: 3  Schema:   QC_hit: No # Query_time: 0.000123  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0 # Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 49
SET timestamp=1700038768;
SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=60 FOR SELECT 1;
```

and then in the `prt()` function you have all of the information about the separate lines from which `rec` was constructed.

Comment: I really like `prt()` function. Upvoted.

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh I upvoted yours too as that's the concise way to do it if you never need to do anything with the whole concatenated record and only has to store 1 line at a time in memory (only an issue for mine if the file is massive and every line starts with `#` so it's treated as a single massive record).

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ed` command below, we join any line starting with a `#` character with the previous line:

```
g/^#/ -,. j
```

What that command does is to apply the command `-,. j` to each line matching the regular expression `^#`.  The `j` command joins the previous line (`-`) and the current line (`.`).

Adding `,p` to print the whole buffer and `Q` to quit:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/^#/ -,. j' ,p Q | ed -s file
2023-11-15T08:59:28.000000+00:00 database-1 # Time: 231115  8:59:28# User@Host: rdsadmin[rdsadmin] @ localhost []# Thread_id: 3  Schema:   QC_hit: No# Query_time: 0.000123  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 49
SET timestamp=1700038768;
SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=60 FOR SELECT 1;
```

Change the two commands `,p` and `Q` to the single command `wq` (or to `w` and `q` separately) to write the edited buffer back to the original file and quit.

Answer (score -1):

```
aws logs tail /aws/rds/instance/database-1/slowquery --log-stream-names database-1 --follow | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n#/#/g'
```

Comment: You may want to read [How to convert all newlines to "\n" in POSIX sh strings](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/761886) about some of the problems with that `sed` code. In addition, there's the problem that `:` and `b` commands should not be followed by other commands on the same line.

Comment: Given your feedback and the complexities involved, here's a revised approach that should be more compliant with POSIX shell scripting standards:

```aws logs tail /aws/rds/instance/database-1/slowquery --log-stream-names database-1 --follow | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n#/#/g'
```

Comment: `N` should be run under the `$!` check.

Comment: Your note about `N` being run under the `$!`check is correct. The `N` command is part of the loop that reads all lines into the buffer, and the loop runs until the end of the file is reached. This approach ensures that the entire file is read into the pattern space for the subsequent `sed`substitution command to work on the entire file contents at once.

Comment: I mean it should be `-e '$! { N; ba' -e '}'`, you must make sure `N` is not run on the last line (`$`)

Comment: It not work pro :( command don't return any result.

Comment: You are correct. The revised sed command would look like this:


`aws logs tail /aws/rds/instance/database-1/slowquery --log-stream-names database-1 --follow | sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba}' -e 's/\n#/#/g'
`

Comment: same result pro, do not any result showing after your guild. And when i'm stop command by ctrl + C screen show error: ^CException ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of adding new versions in these comments, @KristtofV88.