# Change special hh mm to another time zone

Tags: linux, timezone

I want to change 0710 (07 hour 10 minute in GMT +0)
to 0810 (08 hour 10 minute in GMT +1)

what command in linux can do it?

Thank you for your support !

Comment: Are you really switching from GMT+0 or from UTC? And actually, are you switching from UTC to a local time zone? Because if so that would depend on the date too

Comment: yeah, mr Chris. I have research but not have result. In my situation. I process some step and 0710 is the text of my result. And i want to change this text to GMT +1

Comment: So you're talking about changing data rather than the timezone of your server?

Comment: Do you really just want to add an hour to your result or have you been calculating with UTC and you now need to switch that time to a local timezone? (One is simple maths: just add 100. The other is a date/time operation.) If you're converting from UTC to a local timezone you really need to consider the date that the time relates to, because some timezones vary in offset from UTC depending on the point in the year to which the time relates

Comment: Based on [your earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/761874/100397) I'm wondering if you just want to convert the timestamps from your AWS output into local time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to add an hour to a four digit time value you can treat is as a standard base 10 number and simply add 100 modulo 2400.

Actually, it gets a bit more complicated than that because we first have to remove any leading zeros so that the shell doesn't treat the value as octal, and then we need to rebuild the result back to four digits:

```
a=0710
b=$( printf "%04d" $(( (${a##0}+100) % 2400 )) )
echo b=$b    # "0810"
```

On the other hand if you want to perform real date/time arithmetic that may vary depending on timezone (and date) you need to be more precise in your requirement.

Comment: Thank you Chris. It's work for me. I just want convert text result to another time zone. Because my organization do not permit change time zone in AWS server.

Comment: You are not converting to another time zone like this, @dvthanh. Please read what I've written!

Answer (score 0):

You can use`timedatectl` by doint these:

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Use the `timedatectl list-timezones` command to list available time zones. Search for the zone that corresponds to GMT+1. For example:

   ```
   timedatectl list-timezones | grep GMT+1
   ```
3. Once you've identified the GMT+1 timezone (for instance, `Europe/Paris` is GMT+1), use the `timedatectl set-timezone` command followed by the identified timezone:

   ```
   sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Paris
   ```

   Replace `Europe/Paris` with the timezone you found in step 2.
4. After executing the command, check if the timezone has been updated by using:

   ```
   timedatectl
   ```

   This will display the current system time and date settings, including the new timezone you've set.

Remember, using `sudo` may prompt you for your password to run the command with administrative privileges.

Comment: Thank your for answer, but i only need convert text to another time zone time. So, the answer from Chris on top helped for me !